# Error after converting an application from VB2005 to VB2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am converting an application from VB2005 to VB2010. After that I tried to run the program, but I got this error:

> Error  173 The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace xxx

After that I checked through the file, and it was there, but why it cannot run. I also checked the file's size. It was a little different. Before conversion it was 139,796 bytes. After conversion it was 139,800 bytes. What's gone wrong here?

Comment: Please check the logs which are generated when any solution is converted from lower VS version to higher VS version? This may give you some help regarding the error you are facing.

Comment: @Palak.Maheria where could I get the log ?

Comment: It automatically generates a log and displays in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check .NET Framework version. I had some error like yours after a converting c# project to newer version. A converted project linked to newer .NET Framework automatically, but when I changed its version to a source one - it worked again. After return to the old version the error disappeared.